# Laravel Service Container Binding Primitives Not Working For Mailchimp

Tags: laravel, mailchimp, laravel-10

We have the following binding Primitives

```
use NZTim\Mailchimp\Mailchimp;
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        app()->when(Mailchimp::class)
            ->needs('$apikey')
            ->give(config('services.mailchimp.apikey'));
        app()->when(ReCaptcha::class)
            ->needs('$secret')
            ->give(config('services.recaptcha.secret'));
    }
}
```

Recaptcha is working. But with Mailchimp we receive the following error:

```
use NZTim\Mailchimp\Mailchimp;
$mc = app(Mailchimp::class);
```

"Mailchimp API key is required - use the 'MC_KEY' .env value"

```
class Mailchimp
{
    protected MailchimpApi $api;

    public function __construct($apikey, $api = null)
    {
        if (!is_string($apikey)) {
            throw new MailchimpException("Mailchimp API key is required - use the 'MC_KEY' .env value");
        }
        if (is_null($api)) {
            $api = new MailchimpApi($apikey);
        }
        $this->api = $api;
    }
}
```

+++++++

Update, we tried the following update and still have the same issue.

```
app()->when(Mailchimp::class)
        ->needs('$apikey')
        ->giveConfig('services.mailchimp.apikey');
```

Comment: Can you add a `dd` before the `if` just to see what is being sent as `$apikey`?

Comment: It's coming through as null. dd from the AppServiceProvider of config('services.mailchimp.apikey') is showing the correct key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the NZTim\Mailchimp package uses the following ServiceProvider.

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(Mailchimp::class, function () {
            return new Mailchimp(config('mailchimp.apikey'));
        });
        $this->app->bind('mailchimp', function () {
            return $this->app->make(Mailchimp::class);
        });
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/mailchimp.php', 'mailchimp');
    }
```

config('mailchimp.apikey') wasn't set, adding this config value fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to inject a configuration value, you can use the [giveConfig](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#binding-primitives) method:

```
$this->app->when(Mailchimp::class)
    ->needs('$apikey')
    ->giveConfig('services.mailchimp.apikey');
```

Comment: Thanks, we also tried this but it's still not working.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but don't you need a closure when using `give(config('services.recaptcha.secret'))`? You probably tried this, but make sure config:cache isn't used (or make sure it is cleared), and since you are testing for `is_string` make sure the value is an actual string.