# Why is dependency injection of config variables not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm working on a Laravel site, trying to get data from a web form sent to our CRM Hubspot. I've configured it to be a Job but the job fails with the following error:

*Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  string $portalId ]] in class App\Services\Hubspot\HubspotFormService*

This is what I've done so far:

Added the config to my .env file

```
HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID=xxx
HUBSPOT_FORM_ID=xxx
```

Created a config file in config/hubspot.php

```
<?php

return [
    'portal_id' => env('HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID', ''),
    'form_id' => env('HUBSPOT_FORM_ID', ''),
];
```

Added this to the AppServiceProvider, initially like this but I've tried other methods as well. Based on https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container#binding-primitives

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->app->when(HubspotFormService::class)
        ->needs('$portalId')
        ->give(config('hubspot.portal_id'));
    
    $this->app->when(HubspotFormService::class)
        ->needs('$formGuid')
        ->give(config('hubspot.form_id'));
```

So in my mind, wherever I use the HubspotFormService class, those 2 env values should automatically be injected in to the constructor.

The start of the service class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Hubspot;

class HubspotFormService
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly string $portalId,
        private readonly string $formGuid,
    ) {}
```

And I call that from a job file, like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Quote;
use App\Services\Hubspot\HubspotFormService;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Throwable;

class SendQuoteToHubspot implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $uniqueFor = 60;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        public Quote $quote,
    ) {}

    /**
     * Get the unique ID for the job.
     */
    public function uniqueId(): string
    {
        return $this->quote->id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(HubspotFormService $hubspot): void
    {
        $hubspot->submitForm($this->quote);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     */
    public function failed(Throwable $exception): void
    {
        Log::error('Failed to send quote to Hubspot: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have used this same method of dependency injection in other Services but those were not initiated as Jobs like this one, which I suspect is where the issue is. There are other service providers for the app but they don't seem to be more relevant than the App one, barring maybe EventServiceProvider but I think that's for different asynchronous tasks.

There is another post on Stack Overflow here [Laravel Service Container Binding Primitives Not Working For Mailchimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678703/laravel-service-container-binding-primitives-not-working-for-mailchimp/77679140#77679140) where someone describes a similar issue with a third-party MailChimp integration. I tried to apply the same logic but it had no effect. Example code from AppServiceProvider in the boot method:

```
        $this->app->bind(HubspotFormService::class, function ($app) {
            return new HubspotFormService(
                config('hubspot.portal_id'),
                config('hubspot.form_id')
            );
        });

        $this->app->bind('hubspot', function ($app) {
            return new HubspotFormService(
                config('hubspot.portal_id'),
                config('hubspot.form_id')
            );
        });

        $this->mergeConfigFrom(
            __DIR__ . '/../../config/hubspot.php',
            'hubspot'
        );
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with this approach?

Comment: did you try `->giveConfig('hubspot.portal_id')`?

Comment: Yeah, no effect. I think that's just shorthand for the give(config()) method I put in my question.

Comment: Well, it sounds like the job is not loading these contextual bindings into the container. Did you restart the queue after these changes? Can you add a dd() in the boot method to see if it reaches there or not?

Comment: I have been restarting the queue after changes. If I add dd to the service providers boot method then everything doesn't work as expected.

Comment: don t use dd in the queue, it is better to log info somewhere. also restart the queue every time you change the code ( if you are not already doing so). I would try using ```$this->app->bind(HubspotFormService::class...``` in the appserviceprovider. The other method ```when..needs...give``` is unnecessary in this case

Comment: Is there any reason not to just do`(new HubspotFormService(...))->submitForm($this->quote)` in the job method instead of relying on it being injected?

Comment: Also you could set those properties in the `HubspotFormService` constructor, if they're always going to be the same config settings.

Comment: bindings are "registered" in the `register` method, btw